# Curl not working on CronJob in Ubuntu 14.0 (Digital Ocean)

Tags: php, curl, cron, digital-ocean

My Cron-Job looks like this

```
*/1 * * * * curl http://www.mywebsite.in/cronscript/
```

When I execute the script manually I can see the script is running . But the Cron Job is not working .

Now I checked the log since I have setup the cron to send email ,

In my var/mail/myname file I can see the cron emails populating every minute 
but the script does not work

Thanks

Comment: Assuming `http://www.mywebsite.in` is the domain you're using, why don't you execute your PHP (I assume, as seen in tag) directly via PHP CLI ?

Comment: @Raptor I can do that but , The same cron was working until I restarted the Server what do you think could have gone worng

Comment: I can never know what is different before and after your server reboot.